# Add and remove from array carried by RACSignal

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have one RACSignal that carries NSArray of objects of class Bookmark

```
RACSignal *bookmarksSignal = ... // Carries @[[[Bookmark alloc] init], ...]
```

And two RACCommands to add and delete bookmark

```
RACCommand *addBookmarkCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input){
        return [RACSignal return:input];
    }];
...
[addBookmarkCommand execute: bookmark1];
RACCommand *deleteBookmarkCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input){
        return [RACSignal return:input];
    }];
...
[deleteBookmarkCommand execute: bookmark2]
```

Commands are executed on user interaction. How can I combine `bookmarksSignal` and executions signals of both commands to create signal that carries NSArray of bookmarks that contains original bookmarks with those added by `addBookmarkCommand` and without those removed by `deleteBookmarkCommand`?

(bookmarks are compared by `url` property)

I'm afraid that I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure out how to do this in pure way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lack of time, I'll go with a more laconic answer compared to @IanHenry's :)

For anything here that doesn't make sense, please comment and I'll be happy explain in detail.

```
// Map additions into blocks that add the bookmark to the given mutable array.
RACSignal *addBookmarkSignal = [[addBookmarkCommand concat] map:^(Bookmark *bookmark) {
    return ^(NSMutableArray *bookmarks) {
        return [bookmarks addObject:bookmark];
    };
}];

// Map deletions into blocks that remove the bookmark from the given mutable array.
RACSignal * addBookmarkSignal = [[deleteBookmarkCommand concat] map:^(Bookmark *bookmark) {
    return ^(NSMutableArray *bookmarks) {
        [bookmarks removeObject:bookmark];
    };
}];

// Combine the add and delete functions into a single signal.
RACSignal *updatesSignal = [RACSignal merge:@[addBookmarkSignal, addBookmarkSignal]];

RACSignal *updatedBookmarksSignal = [[bookmarksSignal
    // Each time bookmarksSignal sends an array, this -map: builds a
    // signal that updates the latest list of bookmarks, and sends it. 
    map:^(NSArray *bookmarks) {
        NSMutableArray *mutableBookmarks = [bookmarks mutableCopy];

        // Using the update blocks from the add/delete commands,
        // produce the modified list of bookmarks.
        return [[updatesSignal
            map:^(void (^update)(NSMutableArray *)) {
                update(mutableBookmarks);
                return [mutableBookmarks copy];
            }]
            startWith:bookmarks];
    }]
    // When bookmarksSignal sends anew, switch to the newest signal of updates.
    switchToLatest];
```

Comment: Nice. Mapping the commands into blocks that just perform the transformation instead of descriptions of the transformation to perform is a lot cleaner. (Slash, you understood that the `bookmarksSignal` already exists, which I missed)

Comment: Thank you :) Disparate event types lead me to think in signals of functions.

Comment: I really, really like the idea of signal of functions. This is the solution I went with but with some changes. For peculiar reason I need the code to by pure functional so I map signal of bookmarks to function of type *NSArray -> NSArray* (using `arrayByAddingObject:` and filtering) and then i composite the functions using `scanWithStart:reduce:`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's forget about `RACCommand` for a second, and pretend that we just have a signal of bookmarks to add and a signal of bookmarks to remove and we want to create a signal of sets of bookmarks based on that. It's a good starting point, and we can figure out how to implement those after the fact.

```
RACSignal *addedSignal = ...;
RACSignal *removedSignal = ...;
```

Then we want a signal that's the combination of those two signals into a single set of all the added things without anything removed afterwards (we can map it into an `NSArray` after the fact if we want to).

```
RACSignal *bookmarkSetSignal = ...;
```

Now we have to fill it in. We could optimize here by making a mutable set that we modify and just send references to that same set every time a change happens. But that's sort of contrary to the nature of signals. Let's put that optimization on hold for a minute and do it the pure, functional way.

We're going to use the `scanWithStart:reduce:` method, because it fits this problem perfectly. It's like a `fold` that returns every intermediate value, which is exactly what we want.

But first we have to make `addedSignal` and `removedSignal` useful. Here's my idea: merge them into a single signal, but attach another value to them that says whether it's an add or a remove.

```
// turn a signal of bookmarks into a signal of tuples of the form (bookmark, isAdded)
RACSignal *changes = [RACSignal merge:@[[addedSignal map:^(id x) { return RACTuplePack(x, @YES); }],
                                        [removedSignal map:^(id x) { return RACTuplePack(x, @NO); }]]];
```

Now that it's just one signal, it'll be a little easier to wrangle it. Then we can fold those changes into a single value (the composition of all the changes), except that we're reporting every step of the way. So it's a scan, not a fold. But scan makes a bad verb. Anyway:

```
RACSignal *bookmarkSetSignal = [changes scanWithStart:[NSSet set] reduce:^(NSSet *running, RACTuple *next) {
    RACTupleUnpack(Bookmark *bookmark, NSNumber *isAddingNumber) = next;
    if (isAddingNumber.boolValue) {
        [running setByAddingObject:bookmark];
    } else {
        // you can do this with a much nicer helper, but this is the shortest way for this answer...
        return [running filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"url != %@", bookmark.url]];
    }
}];
```

Great! We started with an empty set, and every time a change occurred we created a new set by adding or removing that element. `running` is always whatever we computed last time (starting from the empty set), and `next` is the description of the change that should happen (a bookmark + whether or not it was being added or removed). We now have a signal of sets of bookmarks, just like we wanted!

Except now we need to fill out `addedSignal` and `removedSignal`.

The exact way we do this is a little...well, it depends on the user interaction. We could make each one a subject, and then user interaction would manually send new values. That might be the right way to do it. It's cleaner than manually triggering an `RACCommand`. Anyway, that's a separate question. Assuming the exact RACCommand format that you have now, I think we can implement it like this:

```
RACSignal *addedSignal = [self.addBookmarkCommand.executionSignals switchToLatest];
RACSignal *removedSignal = [self.deleteBookmarkCommand.executionSignals switchToLatest];
```

`executionSignals` is a signal of every signal returned in the signal block. Which are merely `[RACSignal return:bookmark]`. By `switch`ing`ToLatest`, we're basically "unwrapping" that value. But if we used a subject we wouldn't need to wrap/unwrap in the first place. But anyway, separate discussion.

This code will almost certainly require a little modification to do what you want (haven't tested it), but hopefully this'll point you in the right direction idea-wise.